# three.js: use texture in shader material added to object loaded by object loader

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

i've got a problem when i try to use a texture in a shader material used in a blender object loaded by object loader `THREE.OBJLoader`.

This simple code works fine, it is loading a texture and applied it to a loaded object.

```
    var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
    var texture = new THREE.Texture();
    var imageLoader = new THREE.ImageLoader(manager);
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);

    imageLoader.load("texture.png", function (image) {
       texture.image = image;
       texture.needsUpdate = true;
    });
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture});
    objLoader.load("blenderObject.obj", function (object) {
       object.traverse(function (child) {
       if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
          child.material = material;
       }    
    });                
    scene.add(object);
```

But I want to use my `ShaderMaterial` instead of a `MeshBasicMaterial`. This shader material works fine with other objects that i use in my projects. This is initialization of my shader material:

```
        var uniforms = {
          texture: { type: "t", value: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("texture.png") },                 
        }

        var shader = THREE.ShaderLib["shader"];

        var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
            uniforms: uniforms,
            vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
            fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
            depthTest: true,    
        });
```

So when i use this material instead of `MeshBasicMaterial` i've no error but object is just all black. I wonder what is the proper way to use textures in shader materials with objects created by `THREE.OBJLoader`. When I applied this shader to other objects it works exactly like it should. Thx in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All textures are created equal. There is no difference how you create your objects.

The problem with your code is that when you assign the `uniforms` variable your texture value will be null because `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture()` is asynchronous. The proper ways it to use the `THREE.TextureLoader()` documented at: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TextureLoader

Comment: Hi, thanks for an answer, loading texture works fine with the way i use it, at least on objects that i use, but `THREE.TextureLoader()` is much better way, because now i have absolutely surety that everything will work fine. It appears that problem in my question was created by my shader, i desing it to work as one vertex equels one texture, that's why it was not loading properly textures for an object as a whole.